# Jquery in FireFox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, syntax

I've been recently studying Jquery, after studying html, CSS, and JavaScript, and found a very important detail (at least to me). After I finish writing some basic code, fix the errors, link it to the page, and open it, my script does not load. My initial response is that I'm at fault, but that is not the case! http://www.codecademy.com/courses/web-beginner-en-bay3D/0/1?curriculum_id=50a3fad8c7a770b5fd0007a1 is the site where I am learning Jquery and it has a cool (at least to me) example of whats possible using it. I copied its examples check 50 times to make sure they're linked correctly and each time the code does nothing!

Now I did some research on my own, and as far as I can tell:

1. Other people have same problem.
2. I may need a online source for a library
3. There has been no official asked question on this

Whatever solution you may have, I thank you in advance, as I'm sure this will help many who have this problem. I have not tried another browser (yet), but regardless if that does solve the problem I don't won't to limit my site to a certain browser.

Type of code:

Html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Magic!</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css"/>
        <script src="jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="red"></div>
        <div id="blue"></div>
        <div id="yellow"></div>
        <div id="green"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    display: inline-block;
}

#red {
     background-color:#FF0000;
}

#blue {
    background-color:#0000FF;
}

#yellow {
    background-color:#E2BE22;
}

#green {
    background-color:#008800;
}
```

script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('div').mouseenter(function() {
       $(this).animate({
           height: '+=10px'
       });
   });
   $('div').mouseleave(function() {
       $(this).animate({
           height: '-=10px'
       }); 
   });
   $('div').click(function() {
       $(this).toggle(1000);
   }); 
});
```

EDIT: If you please, write the script you would use.
P.S. I have already looked at http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/ and it did not solve my problem.

Edit2: I have downloaded jquery-1.10.1.min.js and put it in the same folder, and have linked it (assuming it is correct) and it has not worked. My code is as above.

Read This to help me: Ok apparently I'm doing something wrong. So can someone make a detailed list on what to do (go to, click, download, download to) and example text to try it out, because after trying to do this for 12+ hours starts getting on ones nerve. Thanks in advance ^_^

Comment: It doesn't look like you included jQuery. I recommend to read the documentation: http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/. It explains how to set up everything correctly.

Comment: you are always at fault. ;-)

Comment: On the site it says to link jquery scripts like above

Comment: @ReubenRenquist You aren't linking to it though. Try putting `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` in as well.

Comment: @ReubenRenquist to link in jQuery, you need to either pull it from the Google CDN or download it, put it in the directory with your other files, and link it from there.

`<script type="text/javascript" src="http:////ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Do you see the `<script src="jquery.js"></script>` part in the code example? And also *"The `src` attribute in the `<script>` element must point to a copy of jQuery. Download a copy of jQuery from the [Downloading jQuery](http://jquery.com/download/) page and store the `jquery.js` file in the same directory as your HTML file."* It's right at the beginning. You have to read carefully.

Comment: Learning how to _include_ jQuery should be the first step you take in learning how to _use_ jQuery.  You need to start simple.  The first thing you should do is write a page that uses jQuery's `$(document).ready()` construct to print an alert... Don't even bother moving on until you can do that.

Comment: Why does someone revert it when I posted the answer. I would delete my question because apparently it is too insignificant, but I can't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens is you are not linking to jquery. The website (codeacademy) does it for you like jsfiddle or any web base "IDE".

You can download it [here](http://jquery.com/)

And then add the reference in your code like this :

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Or the CDN: `<script type="text/javascript" src="http:////ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script‌​>`

Comment: When I goto the download link I'm not quite sure what to download or where to put it.

Comment: @ReubenRenquist If you choose to download it, place it in a folder named "Scripts" in your main directory for your site. Then link to it using code above in answer. Often times this folder is labeled "js", but names are up to you. The part `src="Scripts/...` tells the browser "Look on this domain for a directory named 'Scripts' containing a file named'jquery-1.7.1.min.js'". Although, for simplicity sake, you could just use online hoste jQuery by including  Chases comment/answer in your head before you make any jQuery calls.

Comment: Like I said, not sure what to download :\

Comment: @Reuben: Download the first one: "Download the compressed, production jQuery 1.10.1".

Answer (score 1):

Surprisingly, the training website you linked does not include the link to jQuery!  (A big oops on a training site IMHO).

You can add a link to your `<head>` via a [cdn](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide).  This way you don't have to download any stuff (easier for beginners).

```
<head>
    <title>Magic!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
</head>
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TVeU6/) is a cool place to play with code such as this.  For completeness the rest of the code plays out like this:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('div').mouseenter(function () {
            $(this).animate({
                height: '+=10px'
            });
        });
        $('div').mouseleave(function () {
            $(this).animate({
                height: '-=10px'
            });
        });
        $('div').click(function () {
            $(this).toggle(1000);
        });
    });
</script>

<style>
    div {
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    display: inline-block;
}

#red {
     background-color:#FF0000;
}

#blue {
    background-color:#0000FF;
}

#yellow {
    background-color:#E2BE22;
}

#green {
    background-color:#008800;
}

</style>
```

Comment: I tried this, put with no prevail

Comment: @ReubenRenquist Please be more specific, an error perhaps.  I linked you working code on JSFiddle.  The code also runs fine on my machine.